# HP ProBook 6560b power led blinking white/amber, does not start

Tags: laptop, repair, indicator

I almost am sure this is a hardware issue, however I don't know if this forum (superuser) is the best forum to ask (if not; please say which one, than I remove the question and create a new one).

I have a HP Probook 6560b and the power led blinks white/amber. Also it does not start up.

What I tried:

- Replace battery pack
- Replace power

Neither does work.

Also in the manual I cannot find what it means, does anybody know what can be the cause and/or how to fix this?

Comment: Try taking out the battery, unplugging and holding down the power button for 15 seconds. You may also try holding power+mute together

Comment: See section "Hard reset a notebook with removable battery"...https://support.hp.com/in-en/product/hp-probook-6560b-notebook-pc/5045605/document/c03515402

Comment: @harrymc I tried, no difference.

Comment: @Moab I tried but no difference.

Comment: A bad power brick can cause this also.

Comment: @Moab I replaced the power adapter, but if you  mean the internal power brick, that's hard to replace probably.

Comment: OK, then it must be an internal problem with the motherboard.

Comment: I'm afraid so, but it's too old to spend money on a new motherboard probably.